# Track mail to clients

Tags: c#, beginner, object-oriented, homework

> Create an application class named `LetterDemo` that instantiates objects
>   of two classes named `Letter` and `CertifiedLetter` and that demonstrates
>   all their methods. The classes are used by a company to keep track of
>   the letter they mail to clients. The letter class includes
>   auto-implemented properties for the name of the recipient and date
>   mailed. Also , include a `ToString()` method that overrides the `Object`
>   class's `ToString()` method and returns a string that contains the name
>   of the class (using `GetType()`) and the `Letter`'s data field values.
>   Create a child class named `CertifiedLetter` that includes an auto
>   implemented property that holds the tracking number for the letter.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;

namespace ConsoleApp16
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Letter letter1 = new Letter();
        letter1.name = "\nSender: Justin";
        letter1.date = ("\nDate: March 4,2017 ");

        CertifiedLetter track = new CertifiedLetter();


        Write("Your letter has been recieved!");
        Write("\n");


        Write(letter1);
        Write("\n");
        Write("Tracking number:"+ track.GetHashCode());
        Write("\n");


    }
}
}



class Letter
{
public string name { get; set; }
public string date { get; set; }

public override string ToString()
{
    return (GetType() + ":" + this.name + "" + this.date);

}

}


class CertifiedLetter : Letter
{
    public string tracking { get; set; }

}
```

Looking to see how I could tighten up the code or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Please add description what you want to do. We ain't here to do your work.

Comment: I already complete it , my apologies. I just wanted this to be critiqued and if i could do better on my code

Answer (score 3):

You fail to address the first sentence of your homework: you do not have an application class named LetterDemo.

I'm a strong believer in always specifying the access modifier.  Therefore both your Letter and CertifiedLetter classes should be decorated with `public`.

The name of your properties should be Pascal-cased.  Specifically they should begin with a capital letter, as in `Name` and `Date`.  I would suggest that `Date` is too generic a name, and that you should rename it to `SentDate`.  Why?  One day you may modify `CertifiedLetter` to record a `ReceivedDate`and having clearly named variables adds clarity to your code.

The `Name` property should only record the actual name, and ditch the preface.  You should omit forcing the user of your class to include "\nSender: ".

Likewise `SentDate` should omit "\nDate: " and only record the actual date.  Furthermore, the type for this property should be **Date** and not String.